# Add input txt in FMU for co-simulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fmi

I have an FMU for co-simulation and I want to add as input to this model a txt file with CombiTable and then export it again as an FMU. My question is how can I achieve that since OpenModelica cannot import FMU for co-simulation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Modelica Tools that allow for the re-export of FMUs, e.g. Dymola and SimulationX.

If you want to do it with open source software, you could export the combitable as a second FMU, and create a containerized FMU with fmpy out of these two FMUs, see https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/tests/test_fmu_container.py for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any tools that support such a way to pack FMUs.

You could however make a co-simulation SSP via OMEdit.
First make another FMU that contains the combitable.
Then make a new SSP, add both these FMUs.

Comment: What do you mean by a co-simulation SSP?

Comment: Like fmu, sap is another protocol for co-simulation